# Select from table WHERE column contains multiple comma separated values in a string

Tags: mysql, select

I have `users` table

```
users
--------------------------------
| user_id | name | hobbies_id  |
--------------------------------
|    1    | John | 1,5,8,12,21 |
|   ...
```

with `hobby_id` column which holds ID's of hobbies from other table - `hobbies`:

```
hobbies
-----------------------
| hobby_id |   name   |
-----------------------
|    1     | painting |
|    2     |  movies  |
|   ...
|    8     | football |
|   ...
```

Now I would like to select user(s) (from `users` table) whose `hobbies_id` among others is i.e. **1,8,21**

So **John** from te table above match to mine conditions and should be included in output.

If it's possible I would like to accomplish it by single query. 
Anyway I stuck at the very beginning...

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE ??`

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Fix the data structure by adding a junction table with one row per name and hobby.  Here are some reasons why you don't store multiple ids in a string:

- In relational algebra, columns traditionally contain one value.
- SQL has a great data structure for lists.  It is called a "table" not a "column".
- Types are important.  Integers should be stored as integers and not strings.
- References to other tables should be enforced using foreign key relationships.  These are not supported on lists of things in strings.
- The resulting queries are needlessly complex.

Learn about something called "junction tables".

Comment: Hm. This is the solution of the existence of which I did not realize. Thanks, I'll learn more about it. But now check please if I understand you correctly. Let say I have two `user` of id's **1 and 2** nad three `hobbies` of id's **1,2,3**. My junction table should looks like: `relation_id (int), user_id (int), hobby_id (int)` . And contains 6 rows inisde: **row 1** - `1,1,1` , **row 2**- `2,1,2` , **row 3**  `3,1,3` ,  **row 4** - `4,2,1` , **row 5**- `5,2,2` , **row 6**  `6,2,3`-. Am I thinking correctly?